# Is there any way to run a legacy 16-bit Windows program on Mac?

Tags: windows, boot-camp, 32-bit

I know that the real answer is that we need to choose a new accounting program. Until then, we have an old, no longer in business Windows program that is not going to work in Win8.  Since I'm a Mac user, I was wondering if I could save the day by finding a way to run the program on the Mac. Using BootCamp? or something?

I am using a MacBookPro running OSX version 10.7.5. 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 with 4GB 1333 MHz DDR3.

Comment: What OS was it designed to run on? Perhaps it would work in [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1) if it was designed to run in DOS.

Comment: Isn't the X in OSX for UniX? There might be `wine` available

Comment: The program is Infinity by a company named Componix, org. created in 1983. We have version 4, from 2002, which I think was designed to run under WIn97. It has run under everything up to Win7. We've never tried to run it on a Mac before.

Comment: Why don't you install an older version of Windows inside VirtualBox on Win8?

Answer (score 3):

You could try installing it on Mac using `Wineskin`. With this tool (actually *Wineskin Winery*) you can create wrappers for any Windows applications.

Wineskin Main Page: http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php

If the info on this page is a bit ambiguous, you can [search for some video tutorials](https://www.google.ro/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&q=wineskin%20making%20a%20wrapper&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbm=vid&fp=1).

It's not that hard once you did your first wrapper. There are some advanced configuration options, like Winetricks, but a normal application should work with the default configuration.

Comment: Thank you ever so much, all of you. This gives us several things to try!.